# Orbeon common/global transformation service

Tags: orbeon

I have an xsl script that adds common features to each form build with form builder. I would like for the script to be applied at run-time each time a form is opened. I tried to do the following as explained in http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/other/implement-transformation-service:

In /WEB-INF/resources/page-flow.xml I added the following line

```
...
<page path-info="/fr/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(new|edit|view)(/([^/]+))?"  
 matcher="oxf:perl5-matcher" view="test.xsl"/>
...
```

just before the line

```
<epilogue url="/config/epilogue.xpl"/>
```

And I also added the test.xsl in /WEB-INF/resources/apps/fr/ :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/xhtml:html/xhtml:body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xforms:output value="'test'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the script never gets applied to the forms? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this specifically for Form Runner, you can edit [`unroll-form.xpl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/unroll-form.xpl), and for instance add your transformation before everything else in the pipeline. You would do this by adding after the last `p:param`:

```
<p:processor name="oxf:xslt">
    <p:input name="data" href="#data"/>
    <p:input name="config" href="my-transformation.xsl"/>
    <p:output name="data" id="transformed-data"/>
</p:processor>
```

And then renaming the 2 occurrences of `#data` to `#transformed-data`. (You can of course pick names are more telling of what your transformation does.)